# Copying files from multiple directories to another directory using linux command line

Tags: linux, bash, copy, cp

I have a bunch of files in separate folders, and all of the folders are in one directory.

```
/var/www/folder1/file1.txt
/var/www/folder1/file2.txt
/var/www/folder1/file3.txt

/var/www/folder2/file4.jpg
/var/www/folder2/file5.jpg
/var/www/folder2/file6.jpg

/var/www/folder3/file7.pdf
/var/www/folder3/file8.doc
/var/www/folder3/file9.gif
```

I need everything inside of the folders that are inside of `/var/www/` to be copied to another directory (say, `/var/my-directory/`), but not the actual folders. Based on the example above, I need /var/my-directory/` to look as follows:

```
/var/my-directory/file1.txt
/var/my-directory/file2.txt
/var/my-directory/file3.txt
/var/my-directory/file4.jpg
/var/my-directory/file5.jpg
/var/my-directory/file6.jpg
/var/my-directory/file7.pdf
/var/my-directory/file8.doc
/var/my-directory/file9.gif
```

I can't seem to figure out the command to do this. I've tried the following:

`sudo cp -R /var/www/./. /var/my-directory/`

But, that still copies all of the folders.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Simply use `cp /var/www/*/file* /var/my-directory/`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use find.

```
find /var/www/ -type f -exec cp '{}' /var/my-directory/  \;
```

The trick is -type f that only selects file.